# How to set the style on $document.body in Jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dom, attributes, jasmine

I'm trying to test a function that dynamically determines how many empty rows and columns should be added to a grid. In order to do that I need to set the width of the $document.body. I've so far been able to successfully append and style divs on the body, but not style the body itself. Here's that code:

```
// Set up the DOM
body = angular.element($document[0].body);
mainColumn = angular.element('<div></div>')[0];
reportGrid = angular.element('<div></div>')[0];
body.append(mainColumn);
body.append(classReportGrid);
// Style elements
mainColumn.style.height = '413px';
mainColumn.style.width = '600px';
reportGrid.style.height = '1000px';
reportGrid.style.width = '1040px';
```

Here are some approaches I've tried with their corresponding errors bellow:

```
body.style.width = '800px'; 
// TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'body.style.width = '800px'')

body.setAttribute('style', 'width: 800px');
// TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'body.setAttribute('style', 'width: 800px')')
```

If I log the body.style, it's undefined. Any advice is appreciated!